# Android Background Service triggers event in main app

Tags: android, events, background-service

I'm trying to create an application that will blacklist certain applications (based on user input) and will block these applications from launching by bringing the main (or some other part of my app) to the foreground when the blacklisted apps are detected in the foreground.

This will be similar to Smart App Protector, but with additional trigger conditions.

I have the service detecting the apps fine, but I'm having trouble getting the main activity to come to the front.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this when you detect the blacklisted applicaton:

```
Intent startupIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityToLaunch.class);
startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(startupIntent);
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I was really close but was using the wrong constructor for the Intent. Also, I had to define context as getApplicationContext() during onCreate() of the service (for anyone else trying to follow this). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bad habit to bring your activity to the forground suddenly without notifications. We always recommend sending a notification via the notification manager and by clicking the notification message it runs your activity using Pending Intents. Does this meet your needs ?

Comment: No it does not. The app is meant to be friendly reminder to the user that they shouldn't be using certain applications based on the trigger conditions. Specifically for texting applications or similar when the phone detects a certain speed using gps.
Edit: it's a school project, not something that will be on the market for profit.